# App was force close because Decimal Formatter

Tags: java, android, textview, decimalformat

I want to make string value int show like

[image]

so I put this code in my Java class

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.###.###");
    String get_value = formatter.format(aa);
    a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ttn);
    a.setText(String.valueOf(get_value));

    DecimalFormat formatter2 = new DecimalFormat("###.###.###");
    String get_value2 = formatter2.format(bb);
    b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tfn);
    b.setText(String.valueOf(get_value2));
```

but when i run it into emulator it was force close, and here's the logcat

```
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.example/com.app.example.menu}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ###.###.###
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ###.###.###
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.text.DecimalFormat.initNative(DecimalFormat.java:567)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:560)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:538)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at com.app.example.menu.onCreate(menu.java:162)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-13 23:32:31.128: E/AndroidRuntime(700):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ###.###.###

Now look at your pattern, it's not valid for DecimalFormat as it has two decimal points...

Use the grouping separator (`,`) and your locale will change it to a . in the output if that is how your locale is configured.